# Criteria array for sum(sumifs()) in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I know that the easiest way to incorporate "OR" logic into a sumifs situation in Excel is to nest

```
sum(sumifs(sumrange, criteria1range, {"crit11", "crit12", etc.}))
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to format an array like this in Excel VBA. I'm currently trying to build the array based on the T/F conditions of 10 checkboxes, so rewriting the `sum(sumifs())` for each variation isn't really an option.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I guess there are really 2 questions here...1) is it possible to build an array of string values in vba? and 2) whether the worksheetfunction.sumifs can support the array feature (and if so, what would the exact format of the array need to be?)

Answer (score 1):

answer to Q1 is yes, you can definitely build an array of string values in VBA:

```
Dim myarray() As String
myarray = Split("crit1,crit2,etc", ",")
```

Q2: I'm still looking into the format for using this in the worksheetfunction.sumifs as I find this to be an interesting approach but my question is if you're building this in VBA then why restrict yourself to using the worksheet functions? you could just combine a loop with some ifs to solve your problem

Comment: I spent some more time messing with the array formats and couldn't get anything to work in the sumifs function. I ended up going with your loop suggestion, and it's brilliant. i have a column convert feature to build location (i.e. G12, G13, etc.), and then calculate the results for each cell in the 6x30 matrix. then i used if statements to selectively sum the results of each individual sum(sumifs()) line depending on the status of each checkbox. Works really well!